# How to pre-select option from <select> tag in Angular with options from a different controller?

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

I'm using two controllers here. One, `productComponentsController`, handles a call to our database that pulls back an array of `productComponent` objects. The other, `AddEditArticleController`, controls the 'Create New / Edit Existing Article' page.

On my Add/Edit Article page, I want a `<select>` to populate with `productComponents`, and, if I am editing an existing Article, to be pre-selected with that Article's current `productComponent`.

Simple as this seems, I cannot make the field pre-select with the existing `productComponent`, though it does populate the `<select>` with them correctly. I've tried ngRepeat and ngOptions and both work for populating the dropdown, but neither works for pre-selecting the existing `productComponentID` from the array returned by the server.

My HTML, using ngOptions:

```html
<!-- productComponentsController as pvm, AddEditArticleController as vm -->
<select id="componentBox" 
        ng-model="vm.selectedComponent" 
        placeholder="Select a Product Component" 
        ng-change="vm.changeProductID()" 
        class="form-control input-md" 
        ng-options="component.name for component in pvm.productComponents track by component.id"></select>
```

My HTML, using ngRepeat:

```html
<!-- productComponentsController as pvm, AddEditArticleController as vm -->
<select id="componentBox" 
        ng-model="vm.selectedComponent" 
        placeholder="Select a Product Component" 
        ng-change="vm.changeProductID()" 
        class="form-control input-md">
          <option value="{{component.id}}" 
                  ng-repeat="component in pvm.productComponents" 
                  ng-selected="vm.selectOption(component.id)" 
                  ng-bind-html="component.name"></option>
        </select>
<!-- vm.selectOption() returns true if the current option's ID equals the productComponentID of the current Article. Therefore this option would be selected. -->
```

In my `AddEditArticleController`, I set vm.selectedComponent equal to the `productComponentID` of the Article that was returned by the database, in the promise.then() of my call. While `vm.selectedComponent` does change, this doesn't do anything to the dropdown.

Also, in my generated HTML, I get the option: `<option value="? number:47 ?"></option>` (for an Article where the productComponentID is = 47). Apparently this happens as a result of the model being set to an unknown value but I don't know why the model would be set to anything other than an integer id.

Is this because my select is accessing multiple controllers, or am I missing something obvious here? Any help is greatly appreciated, let me know if more info is needed.

Comment: It's a little bit hard to understand what you're trying to do, if you can provide some demo will be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that because the model has to be a string, I have to cast the `vm.selectedOption` to a string whenever it's changed (in this case, in the `vm.selectOption` function) using `String()`. This is using ngRepeat. ngInit seems to have no bearing on how my code works.

Boom, that's it, and my code works.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)...

```html
<!-- productComponentsController as pvm, AddEditArticleController as vm -->
<select id="componentBox"
        class="form-control input-md"
        placeholder="Select a Product Component"
        ng-change="vm.changeProductID()"
        ng-model="vm.selectedComponent"
        ng-init="vm.selectedComponent=productComponentID" 
        ng-options="component as component.name for component in pvm.productComponents track by component.id"></select>
```

Comment: Using that line with ng-init, my dropdown still shows up as empty initially. The generated HTML looks the same as it did before. I edited my question to include a note about an option appearing in my HTML, though (which occurs regardless of ng-init).

Comment: This ng-init is assuming the value of productComponentID is identical to the the value of component.id for the <option> you want pre-selected.

Comment: Are you getting a populated select list with the wrong option selected, or an empty select list?

Comment: I'm getting a populated select list, but no option is selected when I open the page. Since the database returns a productComponentID, the select list should have the option with that value (the productComponentID) pre-selected.

Comment: I have revised my answer to use ng-options and resolve an issue with the "track by" statement. [See the AngularJS warning concerning "track by"](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions). Also recommend a console.log of productComponentID from your controller to verify its value against an inspection of the <select><option value=> to see that they are indeed matching up.